# Why is the warranty disclaimer section of a licence usually (always?) shouted?

Tags: licensing

For example, the templates provided on the Open Source Initiative website for the 3-clause [BSD License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license), and the [MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license) both include an all-caps warranty disclaimer, though the rest of the license is written with normal capitalisation.

Is there some genuine reason for this? Or is it just a tradition to make the warranty disclaimer harder to read?

Comment: I don't think that all caps really means something is being shouted, I believe that the internet people just adopted it to mean that.

Comment: I think it's to make it harder to read.  It was the only way they could come up with to make it even more confusing.

Comment: BECAUSE CAPS-LOCK IS THE CRUISE CONTROL FOR COOL

Comment: @Woot4Moo: The use of "shouted" in the question was an internet colloquialism, it was not intended to be taken literally. I'm amazed anyone needed that to be spelled out (then again maybe you didn't mean your comment to be taken literally either? :P)

Comment: It's always so hard to determine with online =p

Comment: See the interesting discussion re this subject among lawyers: http://www.adamsdrafting.com/2008/02/04/all-capitals/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Most legal jurisdictions in the US [mandate](http://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/2/article2.htm#s2-316) that warranty information in a contract must be conspicuous. Since source code is plain text, I suppose it was decided at some point that the best way to make text conspicuous was to capitalize it, and the precedent stuck.

Simple answer: it's required by law.

Comment: Great answer to a great question! +1's all round :-)